# Как преобразовать PDF в JPG?

Tags: php

Необходимо преобразовать все страницы PDF в JPG. Команда exec convert преобразует очень нечетко, даже если поставить -resize 8000x11500 - слово не хватает dpi

Comment: Документов миллион, нужно серверное решение

Comment: Используйте опцию `-density 400` https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10928